# What [vectors] mean in smaps?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, process, linux-kernel

I couldn't find any information on what [vectors] mean in /proc/pid/smaps.
Here is a continuous part of some my smaps file:

```
76eec000-76f11000 rw-p 0025b000 00:0c 32363615   /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.0.0
Size:                148 kB
Rss:                 148 kB
Pss:                  97 kB
Shared_Clean:         60 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:        88 kB
Referenced:          148 kB
Anonymous:            88 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me ac 
76f11000-76f14000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]
Size:                 12 kB
Rss:                  12 kB
Pss:                  12 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:        12 kB
Referenced:           12 kB
Anonymous:            12 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me ac
```

I wonder if [vectors] is also related to the previous library libQt5Quick.so.5.0.0.
I need to count memory consumed by a process and particular libraries in it, so I need to know if I have to count [vectors] output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[vectors] indicates a page used by the [VDSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO) mechanism. VDSO is a way of accelerating common system calls by eliminating the overhead of context switching.
Basically the kernel just shares a bit of its memory with the result of common system calls (think gettimeofday() and the like) where your user space process can read it.

You should not count it as used memory, as the same memory will be shared by all processes.